# Why is my article section is going behind my footer instead of pushing it down?(using just HTML5 & CSS3 media query)

Tags: html, css

Why is my article is going behind my footer rather than pushing it down in media query section?
I am only allowed to build the website in HTML and CSS.

```css
article {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  padding: 0.5%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 92%;
  height: 10%;
  color: white;
}

.exlink {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  right: 130%;
  line-height: 2.0;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.footlist>li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  border-left: 2px white solid;
}

div>img {
  display: block;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  position: relative;
  left: 67%;
}


}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>places to visit</h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="exlink">
      <a href="https://www.butlins.com" rel="nofollow">Butlins</a></li>
    <li class="exlink">
      <a href="https://www.blackpoolpleasurebeach.com" rel="nofollow">Blackpool</a></li>
    <li class="exlink">
      <a href="https://www.altontowers.com" rel="nofollow">Alton Towers</a></li>
    <li class="exlink">
      <a href="https://www.flamingoland.co.uk" rel="nofollow">Flamingo Land</a></li>
  </ul>
</article>

<footer>
  <p>StaycationVacation&copy;</p>
  <ul class="footlist">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <img src="images/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
    <img src="images/Instagram.png" alt="Instagram">
    <img src="images/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: From your query, what i can understand is you want your external links to be visible on article section?

Comment: The links are visible, they go down the middle of the article; rather than pushing down the footer they go behind it and I can't seem to make it so that the article pushes the article down rather than go behind it to make it all visible.

Answer (score 0):

@Harris265, I'm not able to recreate your problem, since your code has external dependencies *(images and/or other styling)*

*Always try posting code with no/minimal external dependencies on SO.*

Anyways, I'll write down a few scenarios cases for the footer, might help you and/or other community users understand the concept.

Focus on the use of `position`, `left`, `bottom` attributes in the `footer` class .

---

**Fixed footer at bottom**

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #001628;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
           
ul.horizontal-list {
    min-width: 696px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    }
  
ul.horizontal-list li {
  display: inline;
}

ul.horizontal-list li a{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>

<h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id felis urna. Donec ullamcorper nisi et dui ornare, quis malesuada nisl placerat. Aliquam sit amet tristique ligula. Curabitur eget lectus sed diam lobortis consequat. Morbi commodo augue at turpis hendrerit, et interdum augue pellentesque. Vivamus imperdiet eu ex scelerisque sodales. Nam ac libero imperdiet, pretium ipsum eget, vestibulum elit. Vestibulum semper mi efficitur, scelerisque ligula at, pellentesque metus. In auctor at nisi bibendum mollis. Fusce commodo orci sed eros scelerisque, vitae malesuada tortor tincidunt.

Vestibulum a tellus nec sapien finibus tempus ac in arcu. Pellentesque at nisi posuere, cursus libero quis, euismod diam. Maecenas imperdiet, orci eu interdum placerat, leo neque convallis sapien, vel pellentesque diam erat ut erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus a justo sed sem maximus pellentesque a ac nulla. Donec blandit ipsum vel blandit fringilla. Praesent elementum lectus ut nibh ullamcorper condimentum. Vestibulum elementum venenatis sagittis.

Maecenas aliquam turpis risus, vitae facilisis libero placerat at. Suspendisse sit amet nulla eget dolor feugiat fermentum in eu sapien. Pellentesque accumsan lectus quis orci tincidunt, tincidunt tempus est fermentum. Duis non maximus nunc, at porta felis. Nunc enim dolor, ultrices vel magna quis, congue sodales dolor. Phasellus vulputate tempor ipsum ac mattis. Donec sit amet massa id risus tristique ullamcorper. Vestibulum tincidunt vel nunc eu congue. Maecenas semper convallis velit consectetur consectetur. Phasellus rutrum nulla non sem pellentesque, a euismod mi accumsan.

Morbi et sem quis dolor ullamcorper vehicula a et diam. Etiam hendrerit convallis ante id aliquet. Curabitur ut est lorem. Mauris iaculis dui dolor, et semper diam iaculis eu. Vivamus vel tempus nisi. Duis nec porttitor sem. Suspendisse consequat ullamcorper sapien ut iaculis. Nam ornare ex non mauris sodales semper. Etiam vestibulum odio pellentesque tortor eleifend congue. Pellentesque sed egestas massa. Sed mattis ipsum at urna pretium fermentum. Nam convallis ligula ante, et hendrerit tellus pellentesque quis. Duis sit amet venenatis ligula. Donec id lacus aliquet, vulputate velit eu, lobortis nunc. Suspendisse lacinia quam vitae suscipit ullamcorper. Integer lorem mi, volutpat ac eros non, varius euismod velit.

</p>
<div class="footer">
  <ul class="horizontal-list">
    <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href = "AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Free/Moving footer**

```css
.footer {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #001628;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
           
ul.horizontal-list {
    min-width: 696px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    }
  
ul.horizontal-list li {
  display: inline;
}

ul.horizontal-list li a{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>Free/Moving Footer Example</h2>

<h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id felis urna. Donec ullamcorper nisi et dui ornare, quis malesuada nisl placerat. Aliquam sit amet tristique ligula. Curabitur eget lectus sed diam lobortis consequat. Morbi commodo augue at turpis hendrerit, et interdum augue pellentesque. Vivamus imperdiet eu ex scelerisque sodales. Nam ac libero imperdiet, pretium ipsum eget, vestibulum elit. Vestibulum semper mi efficitur, scelerisque ligula at, pellentesque metus. In auctor at nisi bibendum mollis. Fusce commodo orci sed eros scelerisque, vitae malesuada tortor tincidunt.

Vestibulum a tellus nec sapien finibus tempus ac in arcu. Pellentesque at nisi posuere, cursus libero quis, euismod diam. Maecenas imperdiet, orci eu interdum placerat, leo neque convallis sapien, vel pellentesque diam erat ut erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus a justo sed sem maximus pellentesque a ac nulla. Donec blandit ipsum vel blandit fringilla. Praesent elementum lectus ut nibh ullamcorper condimentum. Vestibulum elementum venenatis sagittis.

Maecenas aliquam turpis risus, vitae facilisis libero placerat at. Suspendisse sit amet nulla eget dolor feugiat fermentum in eu sapien. Pellentesque accumsan lectus quis orci tincidunt, tincidunt tempus est fermentum. Duis non maximus nunc, at porta felis. Nunc enim dolor, ultrices vel magna quis, congue sodales dolor. Phasellus vulputate tempor ipsum ac mattis. Donec sit amet massa id risus tristique ullamcorper. Vestibulum tincidunt vel nunc eu congue. Maecenas semper convallis velit consectetur consectetur. Phasellus rutrum nulla non sem pellentesque, a euismod mi accumsan.

Morbi et sem quis dolor ullamcorper vehicula a et diam. Etiam hendrerit convallis ante id aliquet. Curabitur ut est lorem. Mauris iaculis dui dolor, et semper diam iaculis eu. Vivamus vel tempus nisi. Duis nec porttitor sem. Suspendisse consequat ullamcorper sapien ut iaculis. Nam ornare ex non mauris sodales semper. Etiam vestibulum odio pellentesque tortor eleifend congue. Pellentesque sed egestas massa. Sed mattis ipsum at urna pretium fermentum. Nam convallis ligula ante, et hendrerit tellus pellentesque quis. Duis sit amet venenatis ligula. Donec id lacus aliquet, vulputate velit eu, lobortis nunc. Suspendisse lacinia quam vitae suscipit ullamcorper. Integer lorem mi, volutpat ac eros non, varius euismod velit.

</p>
<div class="footer">
  <ul class="horizontal-list">
    <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href = "AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "ContactUs.html">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```